# Could not load file or assembly XXX or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to .net, I was developing a payment API and it is working fine if I run this application from Visual Studio, but once published to IIS its not working. All the dll files are there in the bin folder.

Can anyone help to resolve this? Please find the Assembly load trace below

**Pre-bind state information**

> LOG: DisplayName = ipaypipe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/paymenttest/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\paymenttest\bin
>   Calling assembly : billpay, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file: C:\paymenttest\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/testpayment/c8a2247b/5876ee0f/ipaypipe.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/testpayment/c8a2247b/5876ee0f/ipaypipe/ipaypipe.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/paymenttest/bin/ipaypipe.DLL. ERR: Failed to complete setup
>   of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.

**Stack Trace:**

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ipaypipe,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.]    billpay.Controllers.HomeController.Success() in
>   C:\Users\SreejithS\source\repos\billpay\billpay\Controllers\HomeController.cs:330
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
>   +58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.b__2()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4()
>   +35    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Controller controller) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9874329    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Comment: This route does not seems like IIS related `LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/paymenttest/bin/ipaypipe.DLL`

Comment: I think its actually getting the file/library and tries to read it. Since you get a `BadImageFormatException` that library must a different cpu/platform or something.

Comment: @FrankNielsen i tried x86,x64 and any cpu but still its giving error.

Comment: @bradbury9 then what it can be, i dont have much knowledge in this. This specified file path is accessible and the file is there

Comment: Anyone knows what this means `Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting download of new URL` ?

Comment: But it is also trying `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/testpayment/c8a2247b/5876ee0f/ipaypipe.DLL` - can you delete this file?

Comment: @FrankNielsen yah already delete that there is no such file exists

Comment: an update to the above issue, the issue occurred is in 2016 server and i tried the same application in 2012 server ( 2 different servers ) and its working fine.